# sampler argument in DataLoader of Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

While using Pytorch's DataLoader utility, in **sampler** what is the purpose of `RandomIdentitySampler`? And in `RandomIdentitySampler` there is an argument `instances`. Does `instances` depends upon number of **workers**? If there is are 4 workers then should there be 4 instances as well?

Following is the chunk of code:

```
c_dataloaders = DataLoader(Preprocessor(cluster_dataset.train_set,
                                        root=cluster_dataset.images_dir,
                                        transform=train_transformer),
                                        batch_size=args.batch_size_stage2,
                                        num_workers=args.workers,
                                        sampler=RandomIdentitySampler(cluster_dataset.train_set,
                                        args.batch_size_stage2,
                                        args.instances)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sampler is not part of the PyTorch or any other official lib (torchvision, torchtext, etc.). Anyway, there is a `RandomIdentitySampler` in the `torchreid` from [KaiyangZhou](https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid). Assuming this is the case:

> 1. While using Pytorch's DataLoader utility, in **sampler** what is the purpose of `RandomIdentitySampler`?

- As you can see in the [DataLoader documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader): the sampler "*defines the strategy to draw samples from the dataset*". More specifically, based on [RandomIdentitySampler documentation](https://kaiyangzhou.github.io/deep-person-reid/pkg/data.html?highlight=randomidentitysampler#torchreid.data.sampler.RandomIdentitySampler), it "*randomly samples N identities each with K instances*".

> 2. And in `RandomIdentitySampler` there is an argument `instances`. Does `instances` depends upon number of workers?

- Based on the previous answer, you can note that `instances` does not depend on the number of workers. It simply sets the number of instances of each identity that will be drawn from the dataset for each batch.

> 3. If there are 4 workers then should there be 4 instances as well?

- Not necessarily. The only [constraint](https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid/blob/ea41e69302d18ffa71a1f3582e71d9e0d055ba96/torchreid/data/sampler.py#L24-L28) is that the number of instances should not be smaller than the batch size.